# Eclipse: how do you add a key binding to an action on an editor context menu

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

My custom Eclipse editor overrides `createAction`, where it registers an `IAction` with the editor.  Then, in `editorContextMenuAboutToShow` I add this action to the menu.

Everything works fine, in that the action appears on the context menu within the editor; and I'm able to invoke the action from the menu itself.

Now, I'd like to add a key binding for this action. So far, I've added three extensions to my plugin.xml: a command, a binding, and a context. I can actually see the command/binding/context show up in the keys preference.

As for binding the command to my action, I've passed the command id declared in plugin.xml as the parameter to `setActionDefinitionId` after creating the action itself in `createActions`.

Needless to say, the key binding doesn't invoke the action - hence this question. What steps am I missing?

Comment: i did manage to get this working, by the setting the `contextId` of my commands to `org.eclipse.ui.contexts.window` instead of the id to a context which i had defined....  the question then becomes how do i "bind" my context to my editor???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a TextEditor-based editor, I had to touch these places in order to provide an action with a key binding:

- define a command, key binding and scope (as you did)
- set the actionDefinitionId to match the command id (as you did)
- after creating the action in `createActions()`, I had to call `setAction( myAction.getActionDefinitionId(), myAction );`
- set the scope in `initializeKeyBindingScopes()` with `setKeyBindingScopes( new String[]{ "org.example.myScope" } );`

Does that help?

Comment: yes, that did it....  it was overriding `initializeKeyBindScopes` that i was missing....